# Third level navigation class

Tags: menus, filters, hooks, navigation, walker

I'm currently working on a third level navigation. The output should something like this:

```
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <a href="#">Level 1</a>
    <ul class="sub">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Level 2</a>
        <ul class="subsub">
          <li><a href="#">Level 3</a>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to add a custom class to the third level list? I've done this for level two with a custom walker:

```
class Main_Nav_Walker extends Walker_Nav_Menu {
    function start_lvl(&$output, $depth = 0, $args = Array() ) {
        $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
        $output .= "\n$indent<ul class=\"sub\">\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to write your custom Walker for that...

Let's take a look on built-in `Walker_Nav_Menu`. [You'll find this function](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/5.0.3/src/wp-includes/class-walker-nav-menu.php#L50):

```
public function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    if ( isset( $args->item_spacing ) && 'discard' === $args->item_spacing ) {
        $t = '';
        $n = '';
    } else {
        $t = "\t";
        $n = "\n";
    }
    $indent = str_repeat( $t, $depth );

    // Default class.
    $classes = array( 'sub-menu' );

    /**
     * Filters the CSS class(es) applied to a menu list element.
     *
     * @since 4.8.0
     *
     * @param array    $classes The CSS classes that are applied to the menu `<ul>` element.
     * @param stdClass $args    An object of `wp_nav_menu()` arguments.
     * @param int      $depth   Depth of menu item. Used for padding.
     */
    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', $classes, $args, $depth ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= "{$n}{$indent}<ul$class_names>{$n}";
}
```

As you can see, there is a filter ([`nav_menu_submenu_css_class`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/nav_menu_submenu_css_class/)) in there that will allow you to modify classes of the list item.

So all you have to do is to add your filter to that hook:

```
function change_ul_item_classes_in_nav( $classes, $args, $depth ) {
    if ( 0 == $depth ) {
        $classes[] = 'sub';
    }
    if ( 1 == $depth ) {
        $classes[] = 'subsub';
    }
    // ...
    return $classes;
}
add_filter( 'nav_menu_submenu_css_class', 'change_ul_item_classes_in_nav', 10, 3 );
```